# Minimal (shortest) HTML for clickable "show-hide" text or spoiler

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, toggle

Yes, there are a zillion questions and pages explaining how to use html, css and (optionally) javascript to create similar things going by the names of:

- hints
- spoilers
- toggles
- show/hides
- tooltips

But I haven't found an answer to this question:

Is it possible to create *CSS* to make something similar to this (a snippet of *html* as tiny as possible) behave as a toggle / spoiler **when clicked**?

```
<div class="hint">The answer starts with an A</div>
```

**If it's not possible... That's okay!** The question is about whether that's possible -- I just want to know.

I'm already aware of the barebones solution that works when **hovered**:

```
<div title="The answer starts with an A. (This is shown when hovered.)">
```

But the solution has to be clickable because it will be displayed on a phone, where "hovering" doesn't exist.

The CSS can be long, but the *html* has to be the shortest possible. The reason why the *html* must be barebones is that I will be typing it manually many times. I don't care whether it's a `div` or a `span` or what fields are specified, just as long as it's short.

There cannot be any other *html* anywhere as part of the solution. That is because in this system I have to type all the *html* every time, whereas I get the CSS for free.

It doesn't even have to be a real toggle: all I care about is that it starts out hidden and is shown when clicked.

Thanks in advance for your insights!

Comment: Well you will need at least two elements, one to click on, and the other one to show the content - unless you want to put the content into CSS as well, but that would likely cause issues with accessibility, SEO, etc.

Comment: `<div tabindex="-1" data-hint="The answer starts with an A">Click for hint</div>`, `[data-hint]:focus::after { content: attr(data-hint); }` would be one of the shortest versions I can think of. (tabindex is needed so this element can receive focus in the first place.)

Comment: interaction needed = use js since css can´t do this.

Comment: It's possible, see [pure css tooltip tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-step-by-step-guide-to-making-pure-css-tooltips-3d5a3e237346). You can switch in that demo (section step3) `hover` to `active`

Comment: to clarify: should the spoiler stay open after the click? so it would be closed by a second click, just like a `<details>` element. see also [Use details and summary tags as collapsible inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57846345/use-details-and-summary-tags-as-collapsible-inline-elements/77550712#77550712)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
Minimal CSS version for custom attribute `tooltip` (you can choose other name):

```css
[tooltip]:active::after {
    content: attr(tooltip);
}
```

```html
<div tooltip="This is tooltip">some div</div>
```

**More complex solution**

You can create rules for custom attribute and add `before` (for tooltip's arrow) and `after` (for tooltip's body) pseudo elements. 
Default opacity for preudo elements is set to 0. When element with custom attribute is [active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active), set opacity to 1.

 
(Source: [pure css tooltip tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-step-by-step-guide-to-making-pure-css-tooltips-3d5a3e237346))

```css
div{
margin: 0.5em 15em;
}

[tooltip]{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
[tooltip]::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:-6px;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-width: 4px 6px 0 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7) transparent transparent     transparent;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity:0;
}

[tooltip-position='left']::before{
  left:0%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-12px;
  transform:translatey(-50%) rotate(-90deg) 
}
[tooltip-position='top']::before{
  left:50%;
}
[tooltip-position='bottom']::before{
  top:100%;
  margin-top:8px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translatey(-100%) rotate(-180deg)
}
[tooltip-position='right']::before{
  left:100%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:1px;
  transform:translatey(-50%) rotate(90deg)
}

[tooltip]::after {
    content: attr(tooltip);
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:-6px;
    transform: translateX(-50%)   translateY(-100%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding:4px 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 80px;
    pointer-events: none;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    z-index:99;
    opacity:0;
}

[tooltip-position='left']::after{
  left:0%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-8px;
  transform: translateX(-100%)   translateY(-50%);
}
[tooltip-position='top']::after{
  left:50%;
}
[tooltip-position='bottom']::after{
  top:100%;
  margin-top:8px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0%);
}
[tooltip-position='right']::after{
  left:100%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:8px;
  transform: translateX(0%)   translateY(-50%);
}

[tooltip]:active::after,[tooltip]:active::before {
   opacity:1
}
```

```html
<div tooltip="This is left tooltip" tooltip-position="left">tooltip on left</div>
<div tooltip="This is right tooltip" tooltip-position="right">right tooltip</div>
<div tooltip="This is bottom tooltip" tooltip-position="bottom">bottom tooltip</div>
<div tooltip="This is tooltip">tooltip without position attribute</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Would you consider adding this at the top level of your answer to make it more useful? I'm seeing a ;TLDR "barebones section" with that bare CSS and the simple html (no position attribute), then a section showing the more complex CSS and html.

Comment: Well done. Accepted. I believe this is a very useful, minimalist answer. I'm sure it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a spoiler type thing with barely any code this might do it, and is pretty flexible.

```css
.hint {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: inline-block; /* you could do this as a full-width block instead */
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative; /* needed for placeholder positioning */
}

.hint:not(:active) {
  background-color: #eee; /* these two colors must be equivalent A */
  color: #eee; /* these two colors must be equivalent B */
  min-width: 96px; /* 72px if box-sizing is border-box; ensures the placeholder is fully visible if the text is smaller than the placeholder text */
  user-select: none; /* if you want it to be copyable, may highlight spoiler text when they click */
}

.hint:not(:active)::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 12px;
  content: 'Click\a0to\a0reveal'; /* non-breaking spaces probably necessary */
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="hint">I am a hint</div>
```

**EDIT:** added placeholder

Comment: Love the placeholder! Would accept this solution if I could accept both. On a phone screen, to leave a bit of space when pressing the button with a finger, what would you suggest -- spaces within 'Content', margins, padding...?

Comment: the padding on this example is 8px (V) by 12px (H). Change the places it says 8px and 12px to your choice of padding, and potentially also the min-width

Comment: Guessing this is more the vibe you were imagining http://jsfiddle.net/umcakyoz/10/