# Use details and summary tags as collapsible inline elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working to study a solution to this problem:

> find a way to implement collapsible buttons (or other similar objects)
>   such that
>
> 1. they can be used in the same line
> 2. when clicked, their content is showed between the line where the buttons lie and the next line
> 3. they are responsive
> 4. style the content independently from the title

I made this gif to better understand what I would like to obtain

[image]

Until now I tried with collapsible objects and with details/summary tags.

It seems that by using collapsible objects it is only possible to achieve the features number 2. and number 4. In fact, since the content (div class) has to placed manually somewhere in the text (so in a fixed place), I don't know how it would be possible to achieve the responsiveness. Same about the point 1., if two buttons are placed in the same line and the two contents are placed in the next line, the second button will use the first content that it will find, but the first button and the second content cannot be used.

Here is some code about collapsible objects

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline:none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: green;
    }

.ccontent {
  max-height: 0;     
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
    }
```

```html
Does <button class="collapsible">this</button> work?
<div class="ccontent">Yes!</div>
Good job!
<hr>
Does <button class="collapsible">this</button> and <button class="collapsible">this</button> work?
<div class="ccontent">no</div><div class="ccontent">yes</div>
Ops
```

Details/summary tags are very easy to implement, but harder to style.

It seems that by using them it is only possible to achieve the feature numbers 1. and number 3., and partially the number 4. In fact, for example, the background color of the details affects also the one of the summary. Moreover, when setting `display: inline`, performing a click on the summary move the text around it in the next line.

```css
details {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  cursor: help;
  
}
details > summary {
  display: inline;
  background: none;
  color: green;
  list-style: none; /* to remove triangle */
  outline:none; /* to remove blue border */
}
details > summary::-webkit-details-marker { /* to remove triangle */
  display: inline;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Does <details><summary>this</summary>so and so</details> work?
<p>Ops</p>
<hr>
Does <details><summary>this</summary>not</details> and <details><summary>this</summary>fully</details> work?
<p>Ops</p>
```

Recap: collapsible buttons have features 2 and 4, details/summary tags have features 1 and 3 (combining the two objects would do the job!).

Is it possible to obtain all 4 features with only one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work for you?

It works by positioning the details absolute (you give them no top, so top is where it would be without absolute) 
Then adding margin-bottom to the collapsible and negative margin-top to the details-element

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  margin:2em;
}
.details {
  display:none;
}
.collapsible.onactive:active,
.collapsible.onfocus:focus,
.collapsible.ontoggle:focus
{
  margin-bottom:1.5em;
}
.collapsible.ontoggle:focus {
    pointer-events:none;
}

.collapsible.onactive:active + .details, 
.collapsible.onfocus:focus + .details, 
.collapsible.ontoggle:focus + .details 
{
  display:block;
  margin-top:-1.15em;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>

    Does 
    <button class="collapsible onactive">on active</button><span class=details>Yes!</span>
    work? Good job!work? Good job!work? Good job!work? Good job!work? Good job!
    <button class="collapsible onfocus">on focus</button><span class=details>Yes!</span>
    work? Good job!work? Good job!work? Good job!work? Good job!work? Good 
    job!work? Good job!work? 
    <button class="collapsible ontoggle">toggle</button><span class=details>Yes!</span>
    Good job!work? Good job!work? Good job!work? Good job!

</div>
```

Comment: This is interesting! But you have to hold down the button to show the content, is it possibile to show the content with one click and then to hide it with another click?

Comment: I changed my demo to reflect different methods. ("on active", "on focus" and "toggle")

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind reply you are helping me a lot. I see that what do the "trick" is `position: absolute`, thanks to this is possibile to achieve feature 2 (content is showed between the line where the button lie and the next line). In fact if we switch it to `position: static` then when the button is clicked the words after the buttons are moved down. The downside of `absolute` is that the width of the content (inside `span details`) of the button does not respect the width of the page (it is larger), so you put all the text inside a container to limit the width, is this right?

Comment: About the `ontoggle` case, I noticed that if i click on the button the content is showed but then if I click anywhere in the page (or even if I click somewhere outside the browser) the button is closed (that is the content is hidden). I think that this is due to the `focus` class, is it possibile to modify this in such a way that the button is closed only if the click is performed on the button?

Answer (score 0):

inline details are not possible with pure CSS
because browsers ignore `details { display: inline; }`
(i would call that a bug)

as a workaround, i use some javascript
to replace `details` with `span.details`
and `summary` with `span.summary`

this will show the closed details as `[Spoiler]`
and the open details as `[Spoiler: spoiler text]`

with javascript off
the open `[Spoiler]` becomes a `display:block` element

maybe there is another way to fix this in CSS
but i have not-yet found it

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>inline spoiler</title>
  <style>
    /* inline details to show a spoiler text */
    /* CSS limitation: the spoiler is not inline */
    details, span.details {
      /* CSS: this only works for content after <details> as long <details> is closed */
      display: inline;
    }
    details>summary, span.details>span.summary {
      /* remove the triangle left of <summary> */
      display: inline;
      /* <summary> is clickable. show it */
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    details>summary:before, span.details>span.summary:before {
      content: "[";
    }
    details>summary:after, span.details>span.summary:after {
      content: "]";
    }
    details[open]>summary:after, span.details[open]>span.summary:after {
      content: ":";
      display: inline;
    }
    span.details[closed]>*:not(span.summary) {
      display: none;
    }
    details[open]:after, span.details[open]:after {
      content: "]";
      display: inline;
      /* remove extra space before "]" */
      margin-left:-0.25em;
    }
    details>summary>*, span.details>span.summary>* {
      /* fix block elements in <summary> */
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function makeInlineDetails() {
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("details")).map(details => {
        // perf: hide details to avoid onscreen repaints
        const displayBak = details.style.display;
        // note: this will add an empty "style" attribute to spanDetails
        details.style.display = "none";
        const spanDetails = document.createElement("span");
        // move child nodes from details to spanDetails
        while (details.firstChild) {
          if (details.firstChild.localName == "summary") {
            const summary = details.firstChild;
            const spanSummary = document.createElement("span");
            // move child nodes from summary to spanSummary
            while (summary.firstChild) {
              spanSummary.appendChild(summary.firstChild);
            }
            // copy attributes from summary to spanSummary
            for (let i = summary.attributes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
              spanSummary.attributes.setNamedItem(summary.attributes[i].cloneNode());
            }
            spanSummary.classList.add("summary");
            spanSummary.onclick = (event) =>  {
              const spanDetails = event.target.parentNode;
              if (spanDetails.hasAttribute("open")) {
                spanDetails.removeAttribute("open", "");
                spanDetails.setAttribute("closed", "");
              }
              else {
                spanDetails.removeAttribute("closed", "");
                spanDetails.setAttribute("open", "");
              }
            };
            spanDetails.appendChild(spanSummary);
            details.removeChild(details.firstChild);
          }
          else {
            spanDetails.appendChild(details.firstChild);
          }
        }
        // copy attributes from details to spanDetails
        for (let i = details.attributes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            spanDetails.attributes.setNamedItem(details.attributes[i].cloneNode());
        }
        spanDetails.classList.add("details");
        if (!spanDetails.hasAttribute("open")) {
          spanDetails.setAttribute("closed", "");
        }
        if (displayBak != "block") {
            spanDetails.style.display = displayBak;
        }
        else {
            spanDetails.style.display = "inline";
        }
        details.replaceWith(spanDetails);
      });
    }
    //window.onload = makeInlineDetails();
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
  <button onClick="makeInlineDetails()">makeInlineDetails()</button>
</p>
<div>
  (text before spoiler, text before spoiler, text before spoiler,
  text before spoiler, text before spoiler, text before spoiler,
  text before spoiler, text before spoiler, text before spoiler)
  <details>
    <summary>Spoiler</summary>
    <span>
      (spoiler text, spoiler text, spoiler text,
      spoiler text, spoiler text, spoiler text,
      spoiler text, spoiler text, spoiler text)
    </span>
  </details>
  (text after spoiler, text after spoiler, text after spoiler,
  text after spoiler, text after spoiler, text after spoiler,
  text after spoiler, text after spoiler, text after spoiler)
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't seem to have feature 2 though

Comment: fixed by adding some javascript. sadly this is not possible with pure CSS, because browsers ignore `details { display: inline; }`